# how to force gradle to show cmake server json response when doing generateJsonModel task

Tags: gradle, cmake

I use **gradle** to build c++ android project using cmake. If task `generateJsonModel` failed I can try again with flag `--info` and see cmake-server json response in logs. But if everything build fine gradle don't show cmake-server json response, but I want to see it. How to force gradle to dump this logs even when everything build ok? I play with different versions of cmake so with 3.6 all ok but with 3.14 `generateJsonModel` failed. I just want to compare cmake-server json response for 3.6 vs 3.14.